# How do you write a regular expression with optional character * at the end of a TIN?

Tags: c#, regex

The regular expression for a TIN is `^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$`, but I need to accept the following (with or without the "*"):

123-45-6789 or 123-45-6789*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make it match one `*` (normally a special character, but escaped with the backslash it becomes the literal `*` character), optionally (with `?`, which means 0 or 1 of the previous):

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\*?$
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\*?$
```

The \ escapes the *, the ? means it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given by the previous users. In C# you might see an underline if the expression isn't escaped for the special character 'backslash'.

The easiest way to escape the expression backslashes is to prefix the expression string with an @ symbol before writing the pattern and is more readable.

```
    string example1 = @"^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\*?$";
```

The manual way is to escape the backslash character is to add another one before the existing one (but the final expression looks messier).

```
    string example2 = "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\*?$";
```

Note: It is not necessary to escape the expression in this manner with VB.NET

```
    Dim example3 As String = "^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\*?$"
```

Comment: Really thorough explanation.